# How to do passed the maven task of bamboo?

Tags: maven, bamboo

I have a bamboo plan with job and tasks inside. I have a maven task and final task after.

How can to do that job depends on the performing result of final tasks and does not depends on result of maven task?

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>my.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-suite</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>smp</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>my-test-suite</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <allure.version>1.4.17</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.maven.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.maven.compiler.plugin>
    <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
    <version.junit.cucumber>1.2.4</version.junit.cucumber>
    <version.cucumber.picocontainer>1.2.4</version.cucumber.picocontainer>
    <version.maven.cucumber.reporting>0.0.4</version.maven.cucumber.reporting>
    <cucumber.features.dir>src/test/resources/features</cucumber.features.dir>
    <feature>features</feature>
    <tag1>~@no-tag-specified</tag1>
    <tag2>~@no-tag-specified</tag2>
    <browser>firefox</browser>
    <remote>false</remote>
    <planName></planName>
    <cucumber.maven.report>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-html-reports-extended</cucumber.maven.report>
    <cucumber.json>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumber.json>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit.cucumber}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${version.cucumber.picocontainer}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-java-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>runOneFeature</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/MainRun.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                            </argLine>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <cucumber.options>
                                    <![CDATA[--tags ${tag1} --tags ${tag2} ${cucumber.features.dir}/${feature}]]>
                                </cucumber.options>
                                <browser>${browser}</browser>
                                <remote>${remote}</remote>
                                <propertyName>env</propertyName>
                                <propertyName>BUILD_NUMBER</propertyName>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureRunListener,my.test.${project.name}.tests.FailedTestListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>runSeveralFeatures</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/MainRun.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                            </argLine>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <cucumber.options>
                                    <![CDATA[--tags ${tag1} --tags ${tag2} ${feature}]]>
                                </cucumber.options>
                                <browser>${browser}</browser>
                                <remote>${remote}</remote>
                                <propertyName>env</propertyName>
                                <propertyName>BUILD_NUMBER</propertyName>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureRunListener,my.test.${project.name}.tests.FailedTestListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>reRunProfile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/ReRunMainRun.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                            </argLine>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <browser>${browser}</browser>
                                <remote>${remote}</remote>
                                <propertyName>env</propertyName>
                                <propertyName>BUILD_NUMBER</propertyName>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureRunListener,my.test.${project.name}.tests.FailedTestListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Unclear. Could you post your POM and what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: The maven profile has been added

Comment: Not just the profile, could you post the whole POM?

Comment: and then I've tried to perform -am -pl smp -PrunSeveralFeatures clean verify -Dtag1=~@skip -Dtag2=~@pre-setup -Dbrowser=firefox -Dremote=true -Dfeature="'src/test/resources/features/node-2/Login.feature''src/test/resources/features/node-2/Logout.feature'"

Comment: I would like to perform maven task on bamboo, then if it was failed - need to perform second task with failed scenarios. And performing result of bamboo job should be depend on second task but not first maven task

Comment: I mean it runs on bamboo ci server as maven task